# Error while running a hibernate program in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven

I was trying to run a hibernate sample in eclipse and I am getting

Referenced classpath provider does not exist: org.maven.ide.eclipse.launchconfig.classpathProvider

I just uninstalled maven from eclipse but I think I need to make some changes in configuration to make my program work now.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 1):

If you are no longer using `maven eclipse plugin`, then you should regenerate your eclipse configuration with

```
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

This will make available all the project dependencies to eclipse.

Comment: is this eclipse.ini. if it is then do I just add this statement in the file? Thanks.

Comment: @Sid. This is a maven command which you need to run from the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem from some old maven settings; it was stuck between maven nature and default.

You can right click the **project -> Configure -> Convert to Maven Project**. Now that you have the maven option you can do right click **project -> Maven -> Disable Maven Nature**.

This got it unstuck for me, but you could also manually fix it in the .classpath file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your workspace. Projects -> Clean...